# Google crawler does not translate #! to _escaped_fragment_ mapping in ajax application

Tags: ajax, google-plus, single-page-application, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I have a single page applicaton that is supposed to use `#!` (hash bang) for navigation. I now read Google's specification on [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification). How can I test that my application works in the required way?

I entered my application in the [google plus debugger](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), e.g. http://www.mysite.org/de#!foo=bar. However, apache's access log tells me that the google crawler then does not translate `#!` to `_escaped_fragment_`, hence the google debugger still retrieves `/de` without the hash bang:

```
66.249.81.165 - - [06/Mar/2014:15:54:06 +0100] "GET /de HTTP/1.1" 200 177381 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; X11; Linux x86_64; Google-StructuredDataTestingTool; +http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)"
```

(Note well: `GET /de` without  `_escaped_fragment_ hash` fragment still). I'd expect Google to retrieve something like this instead:

```
... "GET /de?_escaped_fragment_ mapping HTTP/1.1" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know is _escaped_fragment_= with the = at the end.
Have you tried with:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
```

on your HTML head?